# Calculate angle with two points c#

Tags: c#, draw, angle

I have a line (DrawLine-Event) with the points (a,b) (c,d) and now I want to calculate the angle of it but I don't know how.

I tried it like this:

```
double atan = ((d - b) / c - a)) * Math.PI / 180;
double solution = Math.Atan(atan);
int angle = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(solution * 180 / Math.PI));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483999/using-atan2-to-find-angle-between-two-vectors or use the dot product.

Comment: remove `* Math.PI / 180` from the first line

Comment: still doesnt work...

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622850/getting-values-from-mouse-hover-on-a-class-object-c-sharp/29644962?s=1|0.4902#29644962)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Vector.AngleBetween Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.anglebetween(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the angle

```
private Double angleBetweenExample()
{
    Vector vector1 = new Vector(20, 30);
    Vector vector2 = new Vector(45, 70);
    Double angleBetween;

    // angleBetween is approximately equal to 0.9548
    angleBetween = Vector.AngleBetween(vector1, vector2);

    return angleBetween;

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be the angle between the two points and not the angle of the line with those two points?

Comment: Yeah I need the angle between the line and the horizontal line.. 
And I never worked with vectors..

Comment: @bravobyte Is your line passing through origin?