# Check if a point resides inside a leaflet semiCircle

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have some cell sites: every cell has angle degree orientation and a range in km
I fetch these cells from the db and represent them on a leaflet map with semiCircles as shown here :
[screenshot of my map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbhYG.png)

And I have a home address (coords) that I want to check if it is covered by (one or some) of the cells

As I couldn't find a way to check if a point(home) resides inside a semiCircle, I decided to convert my semiCircle to L.Geojson in order to use the [leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) plugin

Converstion code :

```
let cellGeojson = {
                "features": [
                    {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": cell.id,
                            "name": cell.name,
                            "coords": cell.latitude + "," + cell.longitude,
                            "lat": cell.latitude,
                            "long": cell.longitude,
                            "location": cell.location,
                            "azimuth": cell.azimuth,
                        },
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [cell.longitude, cell.latitude]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
            let cellLayer = L.geoJSON(cellGeojson, {
                pointToLayer: function (pointFeature, latlng) {
                    let rangeMarker = L.semiCircle([cell.latitude,cell.longitude], {
                        radius: cell.range,
                        startAngle: cell.angle - 30,
                        stopAngle: cell.angle + 30
                    });
                    return rangeMarker;
                },
            }).addTo(this.map)
```

But when I use the `leafletPip.pointInLayer(home, cellLayer, [false])` it return always an empty array that means the home is not covered by any cell, I think the cause is that the semiCircle created by the pointToLayer function is just a marker and its layer is treated as a point

I've tried other leaflet plugins such as [Leaflet.PointInPolygon](https://github.com/hayeswise/Leaflet.PointInPolygon#:%7E:text=PointInPolygon%20is%20a%20Leaflet%20plugin,Polygon%20%2C%20L.) ... but it doesn't work cuz the semiCircle is not a polygon

So I need your help to determine if the home is covered or no

and I'm sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are using the plugin **jieter/Leaflet-semicircle**.

This plugin already implements a function `_containsPoint(p)` which you could call using
`p = map.latLngToLayerPoint(L.latLng(yourXCoord,yourYCoord))`.
The function expects a `L.point`, which you will have to convert to first using your maps `latLngToLayerPoint()` function.
Reference: https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle/blob/master/Semicircle.js

If that doesn't work or you are using a different plugin, you could also implement this function yourself (possibly using the above-mentioned file for guidance).
This is not completly trivial, but should be possible with the following Ressources:

How-To: [How to determine whether a point (X,Y) is contained within an arc section of a circle (i.e. a Pie slice)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270785/how-to-determine-whether-a-point-x-y-is-contained-within-an-arc-section-of-a-c)

1. Determine the (simplified) Radius using Pythagoras or (more accurate) [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)
2. [Find the angle between two points in a 2d-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596513/find-the-bearing-angle-between-two-points-in-a-2d-space)

Comment: thanks @B. Raabe
Yes, I use jieter/Leaflet-semicircle
When I try to use cell._containsPoint({x:home.lat, y:home.lng} I got TypeError: p.distanceTo is not a function

Comment: Thank you so much Mr @B. Raabe for your time.
I've tried that also but it return always false; so I opened the issue https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle/issues/42
You can take a look to it there is a screenshot and more deteals. btw I'm so thankful for your help

Comment: You are welcome! I just tested it and it does appear to be broken. I don't fully understand the problem yet, but I will try to find a solution tomorrow.

Comment: Ok I'll wait for you. And in the meanwhile I will continue trying to know what's wrong.

Comment: I have found it. You will have to convert your Coordinates to a L.point first. (L.point is the position an the map in pixels, not Latitude/Longitude). Your Map-Object provides a function `latLngToLayerPoint( )` for that. I will update my answer accordingly. (Full call: `cell._containsPoint(map.latLngToLayerPoint(L.latLng([51.7039,10.2169])))`

Comment: That's worked fine, I just replaced the param of L.latLng() in your comment to be L.latLng(51.7039,10.2169), it receives (a, b) and no array. thank you so much 
B. Raabe you saved me